# how to list "shared with me" items via new google drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api

When I look via web I have four files in "shared with me" folder: file1, file2, file3, fil4. I don`t own them (I can write/reade only). I tried get them with file.list method with parameter
    q = 'not (myId) in owners'.
After that the results contain only one item of the four file1. When I do
    q = 'not (myId) in owners' and title = 'file2'
After that the results contain only one item file2. Somebody can tell me why? Or how to list them in other way?

UPDATE. After some time `"q = not 'me' in owner"` returns empty array (. Below result of `"q = not 'me' in owners and title = 'File Name'"`

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "etag": "\"dTUgP0s1WO8T7wOSfuvve0A4d_k/7dZrNXLata7h1mdbx2RHkqdePEM\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=not+'me'+in+owners+and+title+%3D+'File+Name'",
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY",
   "etag": "\"dTUgP0s1WO8T7wOSfuvve0A4d_k/MTM0MjE4MDUzNjUyNg\"",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY",
   "alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/a/readdle.com/document/d/1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY/edit",
   "embedLink": "https://docs.google.com/a/readdle.com/document/d/1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4Sa5JB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY/preview",
   "thumbnailLink": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY&v=270&s=AMedNnoAAAAAUE-eryR5NIqdEWR3A7bza730sDHhziBH&sz=s220",
   "title": "File Name",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
   "labels": {
    "starred": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "trashed": false,
    "restricted": false,
    "viewed": true
   },
   "createdDate": "2012-03-19T08:37:26.636Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-07-13T11:55:36.526Z",
   "modifiedByMeDate": "2012-05-11T13:02:10.901Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2012-09-04T14:44:32.193Z",
   "sharedWithMeDate": "2012-05-11T10:15:44.221Z",
   "parents": [
   ],
   "exportLinks": {
    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY&exportFormat=odt",
    "application/msword": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY&exportFormat=doc",
    "text/html": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY&exportFormat=html",
    "application/rtf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY&exportFormat=rtf",
    "text/plain": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY&exportFormat=txt",
    "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY&exportFormat=pdf"
   },
   "userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "etag": "\"dTUgP0s1WO8T7wOSfuvve0A4d_k/b2rD7cIZxsGVuxg2MbXoc17PSQU\"",
    "id": "me",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1L8lfBYZHV59uUVpFspFdeW4SaJB7eo3CgPe59kpNCmY/permissions/me",
    "role": "writer",
    "type": "user"
   },
   "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
   "ownerNames": [
    "Owner Name"
   ],
   "lastModifyingUserName": "Owner Name",
   "editable": true,
   "writersCanShare": true
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like now everything is all right. I can see all shared with me files with q = not 'me' in owners. So the answer is "google did some work with their google drive api" )

Thanks to all who helped me to understand that

Answer (score 8):

q=sharedWithMe also should return all the shared with you list of files.

Comment: Thanks for answer..listrequest.Q = "sharedWithMe";

Answer (score 1):

Is this a trick question? :-)

"When I do q = 'not (myId) in owners' **and title = 'file2'** After that the results contain only one item **file2**."

Comment: You are right. It is google trick. I should get **all 4 files including file2** with q='not me in owners' because I get file2 with q = 'not (myId) in owners' and title = 'file2'. Am I right?

Comment: My apologies, your question got lost in translation. You're saying that
q = 'not (myId) in owners' and title = 'file2' returns file2, but q='not me in owners' returns only file1? The only way I can recreate those symptoms are by including maxresults=1 in the query.

Have you tried doing the query online using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it

When I try it, I get the expected results

Comment: thanks, but I tried it with google console and inside the code and had the same wrong results (. So I think It happens with non "google drive files" which were created before.

Comment: It might be worth posting the item JSON for each of file1 and file2. Maybe somebody can spot what it is about file2 that prevents it being returned in q='not me in owners'.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly correct, you having created the file does not mean you are not an owner. The owner permission could have been added for you to the file.

The query should work:

```
q=not 'user@example.org' in owners
```